# eclipse egit: Menu item and keyboard shortcut for Team -> Show in History

Tags: eclipse, egit

Is there a way to get the git log, ie: "Team -> Show in History" appear as a menu item on the main menu bar and to have a shortcut for it?

I'd like this menu item/shortcut to work when selecting a project or project resource in Package Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use **Shift+Alt+W** (that brings up the *Show In* submenu) and then press **H** to activate the History entry.

Otherwise, you can also consider linking the History view to the selection by activating the toolbar icon with the two arrows in the History view.

Answer (score 0):

The command "Team -> Show History" cannot be processed unless it's associated with a module or a folder.

That's why it's a right click menu option.

Comment: I see, so a main menu item won't work. But is there a way to get the shortcut to work when a project or project resource in Package Explorer is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the `Show In (History)` command to a key in the `Preferences>General>Keys` page.  You have to select something before you execute it (like a git repo or a project in the explorer).

Comment: The shortcut works but only when selecting a repo in the Git repositories window. I'd like this to work when selecting a project or project resource in Package Explorer.

Comment: This works for me when selecting a project in the package explorer.  What version of EGit are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers (Indigo SR1 build 20110916-0149) with egit version 1.1.0.201109151100-r. I am trying this while in the Java perspective. I've bound CTRL+G to "Show in History" when "In Widows".

Comment: I'm using 1.3.0, there have been a lot of fixes in EGit since 1.1.  Is it possible for you to install 1.3 into your Eclipse (it might not be depending on how they built the product).  http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've installed Egit 1.3.0 but I still can't select a project in the Package Explorer and have my keyboard shortcut (CTRL-G) work :-( and other ideas?